# Unpacking and then repacking a war file using batch command is increasing the size of the war file

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, jar

I have a war file named CheckIn.war. I use the following batch command to unpack and then pack the war file. I also use a java code to change a value in an xml file after unpacking.

```
jar -xvf CheckIn.war 
java parser
jar -cvf checkin.war WEB-INF
```

But the size of the packed war file is about 30KB more than the unpacked file. This happens even if i dont use the java code to manipulate the value. Is it normal or is the war file getting corrupt?

Comment: maybe the compression settings/levels are different?

Comment: can we change the settings?

Comment: Would help to take a look at what was used to compress the file to start with